# Cannot write to ‘-’ (Broken pipe)

Tags: linux

i'm trying install window on vps but i got error cannot write to ‘-’ (Broken pipe).
This is my command: `wget -O- http://www.mediafire.com/file/7wu3ae2c3dd293i/Windows2008R2_THTH%25402020.gz/file | gunzip | dd of=/dev/vda`

[image: Like this]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the website link.
Instead you should use the download link which you can get if you do right click on the download button and click on copy link address.

Just replace the download link with the website link and try again.